# Proof that if $\lim_{n \to \infty } \frac{a(n+1)}{a(n)} =0$ for $a:\mathbb{N}\mapsto K, a(n)>0 \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$, then $\lim(a)=0$

Tags: limits, analysis, ordered-fields

I want to prove:

Is $K$ an ordered field and $a:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow K$ with $a(n)>0\;\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$. If $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a(n+1)}{a(n)} =0$, then $\lim a=0$.

Please let me know what you think about my solution:

Since I don't want to use that $K$ is archimedean, I can't go the usual way by picking $\epsilon=1/2$, using an induction proof and the sandwich theorem.

So instead of proving "A->B" I show that "not B -> not A".

So let $\lim a =b$ with $b\neq0$. Then $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a(n+1)}{a(n)}=\frac{\lim_{n\to\infty} a(n+1)}{\lim_{n\to\infty} a(n)} = \frac{b}{b}=1 \neq 0$. qed.

Thank you!

Comment: The difficult thing is not to show that the limes is 0, the difficult thing is to show that the limit exists in the first place (which you seem to assume).

Comment: To get 0 (given the limit exists), you can use $\lim a(n+1)=\lim \frac{a(n+1)}{a(n)} \lim a(n)$.

Comment: Only problem: lim $a \neq 0$ doesn’t imply $\lim a =b$, lim a might not exist

Comment: True. I can't see how I can fix that. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

What you need to prove here is that for any given element $\epsilon$ of $K$, there is a positive integer $N$ such that $n>N$ implies $a_n < \epsilon$.

Since $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac {a_n+1}{a_n} = 0$, there must be some integer M, such that for all $n>M$,  $\frac {a_n+1}{a_n}<1$.Then we can prove inductively that for all $n>M$, $a_n<a_M$. Now again because $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac {a_n+1}{a_n} = 0$, then there must exist some integer $N_1$ such that $n>N_1$ implies  $\frac {a_n+1}{a_n}<\frac \epsilon {a_M}$.

Now define $N= \min (M+2,N_1)

Since $a_{N-1}<a_M$, we have that $$a_N = a_{N-1}\frac {a_N}{a_{N-1}}<a_M \frac {a_N}{a_{N-1}}<a_M\frac {\epsilon}{a_M}=\epsilon$$.

Comment: I understand now. How do I know, that $a_{N-1}<a_M$?

Comment: don't I need to say, that there exists some integer $N>M+1$ such that $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}<\frac{\epsilon}{a_M}$ for being able to state that $a_{N-1}<a_M$?

Comment: @manuel459 I improved it based on your comments, note that $a_{N-1} < a_M$ because $N$ is at least $M+2$ and the inductive proof I didn’t sketch out gives us that for all $n>M$, $a_n<a_M$

Comment: thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

A sketch may be as follows:

Assuming $a_n\geq0$ for all $n$. For all n large enough, say $n\geq N$

$$
a_{n+1}\leq \frac12 a_n
$$
Then 
$$
a_{N+m}\leq 2^{-m}a_{N}
$$

The rest should be easy.

Comment: I tried this - but after the induction proof I have to use that $\lim_{k\mapsto \infty} 2^{-k}=0$ (and the sandwich theorem). For that, I need that $K$ is archimedean, which isn't necessarily true for this situation.